# R is not recognizing the levels of my factor variable to allow for recoding/combining

Tags: r, variables, recode

I have a data frame (MyData1) where the factor variable is divided into levels: Agree, Strongly Agree, Disagree, etc.  I am trying to combine levels to make it binary (e.g. Yes if AGREE/DISAGREE etc).

I keep getting something along these lines:

```
combineLevels(MyData1$V45,levs=c("Disagree"),newLabel="False")

>Error: requested levels: " Disagree " are not in the legal list of factor levels:"  Agree  Disagree  Neutral  Strongly agree
```

I get the same issue with the recode function.  Is there a way to figure out why R is not recognizing the level to be able to make produce the function?

Answer (score 0):

You did not indicate where the function `combineLevels` comes from (there are at least two versions). It is simple to do in base R:

```
set.seed(42)
V45 <- sample(c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"), 100, replace=TRUE)
V45 <- factor(V45, levels=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"))
table(V45)
# V45
#    Strongly Agree             Agree          Disagree Strongly Disagree 
#                28                30                16                26
```

Just change the levels:

```
V45binary <- V45 # So we can recover the original if something goes wrong
levels(V45binary) <- c("Yes", "Yes", "False", "False")
table(V45binary)
# V45binary
#   Yes False 
#    58    42
```